# Build WebOS application from existing website

Tags: angularjs, web-applications, webos, lg, smart-tv

I built a website using Angular for TV. I got LG Smart TV with WebOS on it. I'm able to surf to the website from the TV's browser and all is working.

Now I want to upload this webapp to LG Smart TV store. How I can do so? Is there a tool like cordove / phonegap in Android?

Answer (score 0):

Cordova v2.8 and earlier [support WebOS](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.8.0/guide/getting-started/webos/), but it was [depreciated in Cordova v2.9](http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/10/01/upcoming-deprecations/) as of October 15th, 2014.

Answer (score 0):

As any store policy, they have quality process and developers should follow it.

Have you seen http://webostv.developer.lge.com/distribute/app-submission-process/ ?

Basically, the process consists:

1. Registering

   > When your app is ready in IPK format, register the application to LG
   >   SmartWorld Seller Lounge.
2. LG Assurance

   > The LG application quality assurance team evaluates the performance, function, and UIs of submitted apps to verify the suitability for publishing on LG CONTENT STORE (LG STORE).
3. Listing on LG Content Store

   > Valid apps are published on LG CONTENT STORE (LG STORE).

BR

Comment: Does anyone Know here how can i create LG Smarttv webos app using angular8 with webos IDE . i know how to create app but dont know how can i create using IDE ??

Answer (score 0):

look at http://webostv.developer.lge.com/develop/app-developer-guide/hosted-web-app/

"Hosted (server hosted) web apps reside on a remote web server. Users access them through an Internet browser. You can build hosted web apps for webOS TV, using standard web technologies like HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. These apps need connectivity to the web server to run successfully. As these apps reside on a remote web server, you can update them at anytime without having to worry about pushing updates to the TV."

Comment: Does anyone Know here how can i create LG Smarttv webos app using angular8 with webos IDE . i know how to create app but dont know how can i create using IDE ??

Comment: @Nitintiwari Did you find any way?