# Is it possible to deploy an angular 15 packaged app to the LG WebOS Store?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, tsconfig, webos

Related to this, but this question is asking about AngularJS:
[Build WebOS application from existing website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43669333/build-webos-application-from-existing-website)

I am failing just like described here:
[packaged ECONNREFUSED/unpackaged ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: failing to get app runing on lg web os simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052727/packaged-econnrefused-unpackaged-err-file-not-found-failing-to-get-app-runing-o)

Is it even possible to deploy to LG WebOS with Angular 15? Or what exactly could get in the way here, maybe sth related to the tsconfig which makes them incompatible? I was very far into the release process but then the error occured:

FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE: ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND, for those four filenames:

```
runtimemefa9a14c71368959.js:1
polyfillssc5a6162cac4767e2mjs:1
main.607e420b5eadbc63.js:1
styles.56a9653a72393d06scss:1
```

Here is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2019",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2019",
      "dom"
    ],
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "./cypress.config.ts",
    "node_modules",
    "cypress"
  ]
}
```